# Extracting parameters from URL on the server side using java

Tags: java, angularjs, ajax, rest, jax-rs

I'm building an app which uses AngularJS on the client side and java on the server side. On the main page i have a couple of links of restaurant categories which when clicked all lead to a partial restorani.html. So i can know which restaurant category has been clicked i have added an id to URL, so it looks something like this:

```
  <a href="#/restorani/1">Chinese food</a> <br />
  <a href = "#/restorani/2">Italian food</a>
```

Restorani.html needs to show restaurants from the clicked category. 
Here is how my controller looks like:

```
app.controller('RestoranController', function($routeParams, $scope, 
 RestoranService){

function init(){
    RestoranService.getById($routeParams.id).then(function(response){
        $scope.jela = response.data;
    });
}
init();
```

});

And here is my service which sends the get request:

```
app.factory('RestoranService', function($http){
var factory = {};

factory.getById = function(id){
    return $http.get('/WebProjekat/rest/restorani/getById/' + id);
}

return factory;
```

});
And here is my server side code:

```
@GET
@Path("/getById/{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ArrayList<Artikli> getById(@PathParam("id") String id){
    int idNum = Integer.parseInt(id);
    ArrayList<Restoran> listaRestorana = 
  (ArrayList<Restoran>)ctx.getAttribute("restorani");
    if(listaRestorana == null) {
        listaRestorana = readAllRestorane();
        ctx.setAttribute("restorani", listaRestorana);
    }

    Restoran r = getRestoranById(listaRestorana, idNum);

    return r.getListaJela();
}
```

For some, to me unknown reason, i keep getting this error:

GET http://localhost:8008/WebProjekat/rest/restorani/getById/1 500 (Internal 
   Server Error).

If someone tell me where the error is, i'd be extremly grateful. I'm sorry if it is some trivial error, but i can not find at and i have invested a lot of time into it.

Comment: Is there any stack trace in the server log?

Comment: You can make the type of  `id` to be int right there. Jersey knows how to turn a string into an in. But well, internal server errors can mean anything. So: the real answer here is that you do **some sort** of tracing/logging on your server code, to make it *observable* to you what happens. Seriously: wrong approach. Dont ask others what your code might be doing. Instead: enable yourself to understand what is doing. As said: add tracing/logging facilities!

Comment: Please show us the servlet mapping from your `web.xml` file.  We need to see that in order to know whether your Angular JS code is using the correct path or not.

Comment: The path is correct, i've checked that. Problem, i thinks hides in the parermeter mapping, because if exclude the {{id}} part of the path and the request and hard code it in the method to be for example 1, it works.

Comment: Found the mistake. The problem is that the String id was an empty string and when it tried to convert it to an int it caused an error. But the strange part is the path seems ok. 
It says:

    GET http://localhost:8008/WebProjekat/rest/restorani/getById/1 500 (Internal Server Error),

so the path seems to be ok, right? Does anyone know why it maps it to an empty string?

Answer (score 1):

Since this error is '500 (Internal Server Error)'. Your application might have Exception in getById() method.
To Debug this method :- Add debugging point in getById() and run server in debug mode. And look for error or stackTrace in server console.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Hey, thanks for you comment. I found the mistake. An exeption occurs when it tries to parse the string id to int idNum. When i printed the id it was an empty string. Maybe any idea why is it empty string?

Comment: It's not that. Plus i need the @Produces so it can transform my return to JSON so it can be read on the client side. Thanks for the help anyway.